# recreate only a part of database with code first

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, code-first

I have existing project with a huge database, and it uses pure SQL for data access. I have started using Entity Framework and - in long term - want to refactor my whole project to use it, and I have already refactored one small module in that way. I am using code-first approach. 
The problem is : I can not find a way to make EF recreate only a part of database, and leave rest of tables as they are. It is surely not realistic to refactor whole project at once, and I want to do it part-by-part.

I understand I should make my own implementation of IDatabaseInitializer.InitializeDatabase() method. Inside that method I'd like to use something like Database.CompatibleWithModel() method, but on table level, rather than database level. So, my question could be : how could I determine if model is changed for one specific table ?

Comment: You can use EF Tools for VS to reverse engineer selected database objects. It will create the POCOs and fluent code. You can do this incrementally. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Comment: I think it does not solve my problem. I can surely use the tools to refactor one more part of project, but what will happen when I add new field to entity class ? How can I propagate that change to database without dropping all non-refactored tables ?

Comment: You use a code first migration. Migrations don't touch the tables not in your context. The only time tables are dropped is when you use one of the initializers like DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, etc. - but you shouldn't be using those on existing databases that contain data.